# what is the use of .length in array.filter in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

What is the use of .length in array-filters

```
      const filteredMatchedProfile=matchedProfiles?.filter(
          (matchedprofile)=>
              matchedprofile.matches.filter(
                 (profile)=>
                     profile.user_id==userID).length>0)
```

Use of `.length` filter in arrays?

Comment: It's saying "if I filter, and there are still some items left"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `filter` is just a common, but poor, way to see if any element in the array matches the predicate supplied by the function: If the new array `filter` creates has any elements in it (`.length > 0`), at least one element matched the predicate.

The better way to do that is with [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):¹

```
const filteredMatchedProfile = matchedProfiles?.filter((matchedprofile) =>
    matchedprofile.matches.some((profile) => profile.user_id == userID)
);
```

Using `some` more clearly indicates what you're doing, doesn't create an unnecessary throw-away array, and stops as soon as it knows the result.

It's one of the two common antipatterns around `filter`:

1. `someArray.filter(predicateFunction).length > 0` or `=== 0` should be replaced with `someArray.some(predicateFunction)` and `!someArray.some(predicateFunction)`, respectively.
2. `someArray.filter(predicateFunction)[0]` should be replaced with a call to [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): `someArray.find(predicateFunction)`.

---

¹ A better name for `some` would be `any`, but unfortunately when it was being added to JavaScript, a survey of code in the wild using libraries and such found that adding a standard `any` method would break existing code. :-(

Answer (score 0):

.length checks if the array has some items in it if length is greater than 0.